# javascript Carousel does not slide

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am designing a webpage with a fullscreen carousel. The carousel does slide to the next images but however does not display the wanted images. I think the problem lies with my javascript work as  I am not proficient in that language but it could also be html text I have included a link to my program on JSFiddle below

[JsFiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/t3xw0koc/)

```js
 
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');
 arrowLeft = document.querySelectorAll('#arrow-left');
 arrowRight = document.querySelectorAll('#arrow-right');
 current = 0;

//clear all images
function reset(){
 for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++){
  sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none'; 
}
}

//start Slider (carousel)
function startSlide(){
 reset();
 sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block';
}

 //show previous
 function slideLeft(){
  reset();
  sliderImages[current -1].style.display = 'block';
  current--;
 }

 //show next
 function slideRight(){
  reset();
  sliderImages[current +1].style.display = 'block';
  current++;
 }

 //Left arrow click
 arrowLeft.addEventlistener('click', function(){
  if (current === 0){
   current = sliderImages.length;
}
  slideLeft();
});

 //Right arrow click
 arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1){
   current = -1;
}
  slideRight();
});

  startSlide();
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap in this project?  I'm trying to determine what you're doing here, sorry.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including CSS and HTML *in the question itself* . Please see [MCVE]

Comment: @Ryan_D No I did not use bootstrap. I have watched a few videos on YouTube to familiarize myself with bootstrap because it is the best way to create a slider/carousel but I couldn't dive into it because of the time frame of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you have 2 mistakes: one you have a typo in `arrowLeft.addEventListener`, must be `arrowLeft.addEventlistener` and second `querySelectorAll` retrieve an array you have to select the first one, this would look like this: `arrowLeft = document.querySelectorAll('#arrow-left')[0];`. Additional you bind `onclick` and `addEventListener`, only one is necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/xmkdwyer/2/

Comment: Jose's answer is working for me, but you need to close a div.  You're missing 1 div close. Looks like you're not closing your slider div.

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected my spelling mistakes (JavaScript being case sensitive). However I don't not understand your statement of `onclick` and `addEventListener` , one being necessary. Are you saying because I used `addEventListener` I don't not need to call in the `onclick` function in my div tag?

Comment: @JoseRojas forgot to tag you, sorry

Comment: @Muna yes, just with `addEventListener` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your `let sliderImages =  document.querySelectorAll('slide')` isn't finding anything so your script is breaking. I changed that line to `let sliderImages = document.getElementsByClassName('slide')` and it finds the divs successfully. I think you may need to tweak a few things around to get it working correctly, but the images do change.